# How to implement double tap for surface view in android

Tags: android, surfaceview, gesture

Please tell how to implement double tap for `SurfaceView` in Android using gesture detector. Can anybody provide code example?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could try following.. actually i tested this and it works pretty well:

**1)** Extend `GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener` and override it's `onDoubleTap()` method:

```
    class DoubleTapGestureDetector extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Double Tap Detected ...");
            return true;
        }

    }
```

**2)** Instantiate the `GestureDetector`:

```
final GestureDetector mGesDetect = new GestureDetector(this, new DoubleTapGestureDetector());
```

**3)** Set an `OnTouchListener` on your `SurfaceView`, override its `onTouch()` method and call the `onTouchEvent()` on your `GestureDetector` object:

```
    surfview.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            mGesDetect.onTouchEvent(event);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried above solution. But, it didn't work for my case. I got the touch event in **surface view touch listener**, but didn't find any callback either in **onDoubleTap** or  **onSingleTapConfirmed** methods. My Code is given below:

```
final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
            // code here
            return super.onDoubleTap(e);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
            // code here
            return super.onSingleTapConfirmed(e);
        }

    });

surfaceView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
    });
```

When I made the surface view clickable, it worked.

```
 surfaceView.setClickable(true);
```

Detailed explanation can be found in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15343825/5595806)